# Force frontpage language

Tags: ajax, multilingual, joomla2.5

I have got a multilingual joomla 2.5 website with sef urls enabled. The page relies heavily on ajax, so every kind of content is pulled from the server after the good old

```
window.onload
```

event. To make everything work proper and urls look nice, I want to force Joomla to always respond in the sites default language if the page loaded and the index.php of the template in invoked.

Or to describe the problem diffrent:

If an ajax-call pulls an item which is different from the default language and a page-refresh follows, joomla redirects to the homepage in the language of the last ajax-call, that is what I want to prevent.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working! The question itself was wrong! I should have been asking: "How to redirect to frontpage in default language?"

Answer:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$languages = JLanguageHelper::getLanguages('lang_code');
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$defaultLang = ( $lang->getTag() == $lang->getDefault() ) ? $lang : JLanguage::getInstance( $lang->getDefault() );


if( ! ( $lang->getTag() == $defaultLang->getTag() ) ){
    $app->redirect( JRoute::_( 'index.php?lang='.$languages[ $defaultLang->getTag() ]->sef ), 'hallo', true );
}
```

Done!

Greetings....

Comment: Works great and helped me a lot, thanks! I would like to add that the `, 'hallo', true` bit will output a message, and it can be removed if you don't want any message.